# Re-scan python libraries after pip install in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

Every time i install a python library using pip (e.g. `pip install requests`) i have to reload Visual Studio Code, so it starts scanning installed libraries (even when using the `pip install`-command from within the VS-Code-activated shell).

If i don't do this i don't have "Intellisense" for that library and the imports just show a squiggle with unresolved imports.

Is there a way to "fix" this without having to reload the window (`Command Palette > Reload Window`)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have found that you can do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and select `Python: Restart language server`.

Comment: Marked as answer, because it technically answers the question. But this is actually not very satisfying, too, because in the end it's nearly the same as what i did.

Comment: @Incubbus It doesn't reload VScode and is nearly instantaneous which is technically the solution. I haven't found a better way, sorry.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I did phrase it wrong. It's still a better solution. But it still requires manually restarting the language server. Maybe i create a feature request for a watch-mode for the python-libs folder that are checked by the extension or so.

Comment: "Maybe i create a feature request" 
Did you, @Incubbus ?

Comment: @moi i did not.

Comment: I searched a bit and multiple existing feature requests resulted in "Just do 'Python: Restart language server'"